# Primefaces SelectOneMenu next to InputText is on different vertical position

Tags: css, primefaces

When I put a Primefaces SelectOneMenu next to a Primefaces Input simply like this, they are not on the same height in the browser (same in Firefox, IE and Chrome):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head />
    <h:body>
        <p:selectOneMenu>
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Item1" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
        <p:inputText value="Text" />
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Is it possible (with css) to place those two inputs next to each other, such that they can be shown in one line at the same vertical position?

(I use Primfaces 5.1.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try with [vertical-align](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp) property.

```
<h:body>
    <p:selectOneMenu style="vertical-align:middle">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Item1" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
    <p:inputText value="Text" style="vertical-align:middle" />
</h:body>
```

Note that it is not necessarily should be `middle` to make components on the same height. Inspect generated html for `selectOneMenu` and `input`, try different values for `vertical-align`, and find the best variant for you.

Comment: Yes, this solution actually works and it is not even a dirty hack!

Comment: The point is actually that we would want to get the text on the same base-line. It does that nicely when you put an input field next to a label, but not when you try to put a selectOneMenu (an embedded label in a div) next to a label. It is the outside div that is put on the baseline, not the inside text. Using middle might be better, but does not fix the baseline problem1

Answer (score 0):

It's hard when you don't have any parent control to keep the components in the same structure (`<h:body>` doesn't count :D ).

You could try to use div's to keep the components in the same line, and then just align the content, or use the `<p:panelGrid>` component.

Here's one example that may work, using `<p:panelGrid>`. See that I am creating a  `<p:row>` to keep the components in the same line, and a `<p:column>` to separate the elements in line.

Becareful that the panelGrid can resize itself if the space is too tight, inspect it with your browser and adjust the size.

```
<p:panelGrid style="width:400px">
  <p:row>
    <p:column style="text-align: center">
       <p:selectOneMenu>
          <f:selectItem itemLabel="Item1" />
       </p:selectOneMenu>
    </p:column>
    <p:column style="text-align: center">
       <p:inputText value="Text" />
    </p:column>
 </p:row>
</p:panelGrid>
```

Here's some examples: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/panelGrid.xhtml

Depending on your needs, it's recommended to use div's instead of panelGrid.

Comment: Thank you. I also tried to use divs and I also tried a panelGrid. The problem is smaller with the panelGrid, but it remains. If you remove the border-line you also notice a slight difference in vertical alignment. Also, in my special case I don't want to use a table because I want that the inputText can be shown below the selectOneMenu if there is not enough horizontal space. Would you be so kind to show an example with divs?

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest you to modify the top margin in your SelectOneMenu like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head />
    <h:body>
        <p:selectOneMenu style="margin-top: 3px">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Item1" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
        <p:inputText value="Text" />
    </h:body>
</html>
```

With these 3 pixels I see no difference between these components' height.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. `margin-top` on `selectOneMenu` makes both components move downwards, but keep their vertical alignment towards each other. Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

This Css will resolve the issue if applied with textbox whenever we want to use textbox with selectonemenu

```
vertical-align: top;
```

Answer (score 0):

The hard-coded style in the accepted answer is a slight hack.  A cleaner solution is to put a reference to the CSS class for `p:selectOneMenu` in your CSS file:

```
.ui-selectonemenu {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Unfortunately, the text portion of the `p:selectOneMenu` is embedded inside of a `<div>`, so trying to `vertical-align:baseline` would not be relative to the text surrounding the `<div>`.